# Static variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using ES6 style code within NodeJS.

When trying to create a static variable I get an error.

Code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports =  class Count {
    static addToCounter() {
        //this.count = this.count + 1 || 1;
        this.count = this.count + 1;
        console.log(`count: `+this.count);
    }
    static count = "";
}
```

Error:

```
static count = "";
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:646:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: That's simply not valid ES6 syntax?

Comment: I'm copying it from this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Is that incorrect? What should I use?

Comment: Um, yes. [MDN's page on public `class` fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) has the proper disclaimer.

Comment: The real question is, what do you expect from the `static` keyword? What did you think will it do for you here?

Comment: I will be using it to store a database connection. And I want to reuse it in different places within the code. I don't need to initiate the class at all. There will be no constructer.

Answer (score 0):

This proposal is still in stage-2. As of now, without the babel plugin `transform-class-properties`, it is not possible to use the assignment operator along with the static keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not transpiling, you will need to be using at least Node.js v12.4.0 for static class fields. https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--static-class-fields-public-static-class-fields shows supported features across Node.js versions.

Also, inside your `addToCounter` function, you would also need to use `Count.count = Count.count + 1`. If you want to be able to store properties on each instance, then you would need to remove the `static` keywords before both the method and the property declaration.